# Php 5.6 running on docker unable to set memcached.serializer="igbinary"

Tags: php, session, memcached

The default value memcached.serializer="php" seems imposible to be overriden.
The extensions igbinary is there and available but i cant set the value to

```
    memcached.serializer="igbinary"
```

I need to to be able to have "poor man's HA"

It a container based on the standard php:5.6.31-apache.

Well, it seems that I must deploy the igbinary extension before the memcached (because it needs to access the igbinary headers.... as by https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached ). I've tryed:

```
   FROM php:5.6.36-apache

   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \
      # pour installer toutes les déps.
      libmemcached11 libmemcachedutil2 build-essential \
      libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev libmcrypt-dev libxml2-dev libpng-dev 
      libicu-dev\
      && pecl install igbinary \
      && docker-php-ext-enable igbinary \
      && pecl install memcached-2.2.0 \
      && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
      && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt\
           xmlrpc soap ctype zip gd intl mysqli opcache \
      && apt-get autoremove -y \
      && apt-get clean \
      && rm -rf /tmp/pear

     RUN echo "\nmemcached.sess_number_of_replicas = 1;" >> 
      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcached.ini && \
     echo "memcached.sess_binary = On;"            >> 
     /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcached.ini && \
     echo "memcached.serializer = \"igbinary\";"   >> 
    /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcached.ini && \
    echo "memcached.sess_consistent_hash = On;"   >> 
   /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcached.ini
```

But when I do:

```
  php -i |grep memcached
```

in the container, I get:

```
  /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcached.ini,
  memcached
  memcached support => enabled
  libmemcached version => 1.0.18
  memcached.compression_factor => 1.3 => 1.3
  memcached.compression_threshold => 2000 => 2000
  memcached.compression_type => fastlz => fastlz
  memcached.serializer => php => php
  memcached.sess_binary => 1 => 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get the answer

```
RUN pecl install igbinary \
    && docker-php-ext-enable igbinary && \
    mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext && cd /usr/src/php/ext \
    && curl -fsSL https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/archive/2.2.0.tar.gz -o memcached.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p memcached \
    && tar -xf memcached.tar.gz -C memcached --strip-components=1 \
    && rm memcached.tar.gz \
    && cd memcached && phpize \
    && ./configure --enable-memcached-igbinary --disable-memcached-sasl \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```

Extracted from https://hub.docker.com/r/basi/php-coreapi/~/dockerfile/

After that it is only question of modifying

```
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcached.ini
```

and voilà.